# Which Security group take precedence in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, devops

If I create a team's group in Azure DevOps and add that team to Contributor and Project Valid user security group, what permissions will take the precedence? The larger question I am trying to ask I guess is if a teams group is a member of two built-in security groups, which one will take the precedence?(if those security groups are not members of any other security groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new team in a project, by default this team will be automatically added as the member of the groups **`Contributors`** and **`Project Valid Users`**.

Normally, the relationship among the new team, **`Contributors`** and **`Project Valid Users`** will look like as below:

1. **`Contributors`** is a member of **`Project Valid Users`**. The permissions of **`Contributors`** contain:

   - The ones are inherited from **`Project Valid Users`**.
   - The ones are customized specially for **`Contributors`**, include system specifies and you manually specify.
2. The new team is the member of both **`Contributors`** and **`Project Valid Users`**. The permissions of the new team contain:

   - If an item of the permissions has the same setting for **`Contributors`** and **`Project Valid Users`** (e.g. both are **Allow** or both are **Deny**), normally it means this item for **`Contributors`** is inherited from **`Project Valid Users`**. So, for the new team, this item also is inherited from **`Project Valid Users`**.
   - If an item of the permissions has the different settings for **`Contributors`** and **`Project Valid Users`** (e.g. one is **Allow** and another is **Deny**), this item for the new team will be inherited from **`Contributors`**.
   - The ones you manually specify for the new team.

In a summary, basically the new team will following the permissions settings from **`Contributors`** by default.

**[UPDATE]**

If a team/group is the member of two groups, and the two parent groups are not members of each other, the permissions of the child team/group are:

- If an item of the permissions has the same setting for the two parent groups (both are **Allow** or both are **Deny**), this item for the child child team/group is inherited from both two parent groups.
- If an item of the permissions has the different settings for the two parent groups (one is **Allow** and another is **Deny**), this item for the child team/group is inherited as **Deny**.

Update
I am just adding one extra bit to complete this answer-
The above is true if the permissions set on the "teams group" is "NOT SET" otherwise I believe what ever the permissions on the teams group will take the precedence.

Comment: Thanks, I get it that the teams will get the permission from immediate ancestor.
I think the larger question is what will happen if a teams group falls under two security groups at the same time which are not members of each other?

Comment: Hi @VishalThakur, I have updated my above answer with more details. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect, I have just added one extra bit to complete the answer.

Comment: Security groups don't really take precedence over each other. Permissions have **three** states: **Not set**, **Allow**, and **Deny**. Given different multiple states for the same permission for a user: if there is any **Deny** the permission is denied, if there is no **Deny** but there is an **Allow** the permission is allowed, and if there is only **Not set** it is effectively a "soft deny" (the permission is not allowed and not denied). **Deny** takes precedence over **Allow** which takes precedence over **Not set**.